# Accidently ran 'dd' command on external drive - partially deleted data

Tags: unix, raspberry-pi, filesystem-corruption

I accidently ran the below:

sudo dd if=dev/sda1 of=/dev/sdb1 bs=32M count=10 iflag=direct

Removing the first 320MB of the drive has of course made the drive mounted on /dev/sdb1 inaccessable and after reboot unmountable. Is there something I can do to repair/undo this? Should data still be recoverable?

Comment: What sort of filesystem was on /dev/sdb1 ? You'll be able to recover most of the data, except the first 320 MB as dd has overwritten that stuff.

Comment: Rule of thumb for data recovery: Is the data important? If yes, bite it and contact a data recovery company.

Comment: I totally agree with your username. [I misread your username as totalfreakingknob] At least it was your data, I hope! You need to check double check and triple check and have a walk and come back and check and double check again, before you run a command like that.

Comment: It's all my own data.  The file system on /dev/sdb1 was ext3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before trying to recover things it's probably best to create a dump of the device contents the way it is now. In the past I've had pretty good results with [TestDisk/PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/) to recover files, perhaps that can help you out.

Comment: I'm running testdisk already but I'm not too sure how it'll manage.   By deleting the first 320MB the partition table, superblock, etc are gone so testdisk might have a hard time detecting anything but worth a shot

Comment: testdisk/photorec do a very good job of recovering files. However that only applies when the file data is still there, which in the case of the first 320 MB, it probably isn't there anymore as dd would have overwritten it. If you want the first 320MB back, you will likely need to pay to get it back.

Comment: The disk contained around 800GB of data so if I can recover everything other than the 320MB of that then I would be more than pleased!

Comment: I think those tools will be able to help you out then. You may lose the name of the files though.